# Cant select db count rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new in ruby and ruby on rails, so I was wondering, why this code doesnt work ! ( I come from PHP :// ).

```
    class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
        # function for user data

        if ( params[:username] != nil && params[:password] != nil )
            if ( params[:username].length > 3 && params[:password].length > 3 )
                @err = 0
            else
                @err = 1
            end

            if ( @err == 1 )
                @messege = "Hey, yor username Must be longer that 3 charasters."
            else
                @messege = "Ok, We will check your user data"

                result = Users.count( :username => params[:username], :password => params[:password] )

                    if ( result == 1 )
                        @l = "Hey, #{params[:username]}."
                     else
                        @l = "Users data was wrong."
                     end 
            end
        else
            @messege = "Please fill in the text fields."
        end
  end

  def goodbye
  end

end
```

and error:

```
 ArgumentError in SayController#hello
```

Unknown key: username

Rails.root: /home/cdr/perku
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/say_controller.rb:17:in `hello'

Request

Parameters:

{"username"=>"asdasdasdasdaaasdfda",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None

Comment: do you have a field name called username in your users table?Rails is not able to find that attribute thats why its throwing this error

Comment: class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
thats my migration file, I raked it into db also !
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: can you check your DB and make sure that rake actually created those fields?

Comment: Excuse me, How can i do that ? As i mentuned i am new for rails ://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  result = Users.where("username = ? and password = ?",
     params[:username], params[:password] ).count
```